# Jacoco coverage inconsistent on anonymous classes

Tags: gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

We use jacoco, but on different builds and different machines, but the same code and gradle script, it gives different results.  The problem seems to be anonymous classes - they are sometimes not lining up with the test run - even though it's all done as part of the same, clean, build.  We get this:

```
[ant:jacocoReport] Classes in bundle 'SomeThing' do no match with execution data. For report generation the same class files must be used as at runtime.
[ant:jacocoReport] Execution data for class a/b/c/$Mappings$1 does not match.
[ant:jacocoReport] Execution data for class a/b/c/$Mappings$3 does not match.
```

so it's looking like it's getting the anonymous classes out of sync.  Any idea how to fix this?  It's really dicking with our rules, as we have for instance a 100% class coverage requirement - and this means some classes are showing up *sometimes* as not covered.

Answer (score 0):

To generate report based on file `jacoco.exec` JaCoCo performs analysis of bytecode, i.e. compiled classes.

Different versions of Java compiler produce different bytecode. Even recompilation might produce different bytecode - see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8067422 and https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/383.

If classes used at runtime (during creation of `jacoco.exec`) are different (e.g. created on another machine with different compiler), then they can't be associated with classes used during creation of report, leading to message `Execution data for class ... does not match`. You can read more about Class Ids in [JaCoCo documentation](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/classids.html).

All in all to avoid this message - use exact same class files during creation of `jacoco.exec` and during generation of report.

Comment: that's the thing - we are talking a single gradle script on a single machine - it does clean, build, test, produce report - there's no room for different class files or byte code to appear.    And it _only_ ever happens with anonymous classes

Comment: @DarrenOakey Then the best will be to extract/build small reproducer ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ). Investigations will go much simpler, faster and deeper in presence of reproducer as you can see on examples of https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/383 , https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/394 and https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/462

Comment: @DarrenOakey Alternatively use agent parameter "classdumpdir" ( http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html ) to get a class file of non-matching class that was seen by agent, and provide it together with class file that you have on disk during report generation.

And in any case please specify versions of JVM and JaCoCo.